# how to exclude classes from <MyProject>-swift.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, header-files

I have a project that was started in `Objective-C`, and I am trying to import some `Swift` code into the same class files that I have previously written `Objective-C` in.

I need exclude Swift classes from `<MyProject>-swift.h`

for example exclude `LoginVC`

Answer (score -1):

Only the swift class with @objc will generate objective-c interface in Project-swift.h.
By adding @objc, your swift class will be visible by others objective-c class.

Example :

```
@objc class LoginVC : UIViewController{ //will be present in Project-swift.h

class LoginVC : UIViewController{ //will not be present in Project-swift.h
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... Looking for the same answer.